# implement singleton with metaclass

Tags: python, python-2.x, metaclass

the code below is how i implement singleton with metaclass, and it works well

```
class Test_MetaClass(type):

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super(Test_MetaClass, cls).__init__(cls, bases, dict)
        cls._instance = None
        print 'Test_MetaClass __init__'

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Test_MetaClass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'Test_MetaClass __call__'
        return cls._instance


class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Test_MetaClass
    def __init__(self):
        print 'A __init__ triggered'

a = A()
b = A()
```

output:

```
Test_MetaClass __init__
A __init__ triggered
Test_MetaClass __call__
Test_MetaClass __call__
```

my question is why `b = A()` straight go to `Test_MetaClass.__call__` and ignore `__init__` ?

Comment: Your metaclass could be simpler. Not an answer so you'll have to deal with comment formatting.

    `class Singleton(type):
        cls._instance = None;
        def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            if cls._instance is None:
                cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs);
            return cls._instance;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't that what you wanted? `cls._instance` isn't None, so it won't execute `type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`:

```
>>> type.__call__(A)
A __init__ triggered
<__main__.A object at 0x00BADB30>
```

It's through this call that `A.__new__` and `A.__init__` get called to create/initialize a new instance. But for your singleton you only want one instance.

Comment: yes, ur right, i didn't notice `__init__` is triggered via `__call__`