# Using metaclasses to create a singleton class in python

Tags: python, class, initialization, singleton, metaclass

I was messing around with metaclasses a little bit trying to figure out how I may use one to create a singleton data structure when I came across something that's stumped me:

*Also, I have done my homework and looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) page and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895284/implement-singleton-with-metaclass) one too, but I wanted to see if I could do it on my own and the problem that arose is less about how to implement a singleton and more about the functionality of something in my version of a singleton metaclass.*

```
class SingletonError(Exception):
    pass

class Singleton(type):

    def __new__(metacls, name, parents, kwargs):
        cls = super(Singleton, metacls).__new__(metacls, name, parents, kwargs)
        cls._instance = None
        return cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs): #cls is the class being called, in this case
                                        #when Quux is called, the Quux class is sent
                                        #as the cls argument.
        if not cls._instance:
            inst = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._instance = inst
        else:
            raise SingletonError("Cannot initialize multiple singletons")
        print('returning', cls._instance)
        return cls._instance

class Quux(metaclass = Singleton):
    pass
```

Most of it works, like it does indeed raise a SingletonError when trying to initialize multiple instances of `Quux`, but watch what happens when I try to create an instance of `Quux`:

```
>>> q = Quux()
returning <__main__.Quux object at 0x02BE7E90>
>>> type(q)
<class '__main__.Quux'>
```

Does this mean that the `__call__` method in the Singleton metaclass is returning the *class object* as opposed to the instance created in the `__call__` method? If so, how may I fix it **with the current setup I have**?

(I realize there are better ways of creating a singleton but for the sake of this exercise and learning about metaclasses I would like to solve it with this setup).

---

**EDIT:** Okay, so BrenBarn just pointed out that I made a major derp and thought that when it type returned  it was returning the class when really if it were returning the class object it would say . Sorry about the confusion.

But now I have a new problem: lets assume I have a `__new__` method for the `Quux` class.

```
class Quux(metaclass = Singleton):

    def __new__(cls, thing):
        name = cls.__name__
        parents = cls.__bases__
        kwargs = {'thing' : thing}
        return super(Quux, cls).__new__(cls, thing)
```

It raises a TypeError saying that `object.__new__() takes no parameters`. How can I fix this `__new__` method to return an instance of the Quux class?

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your second question.  However, just FYI, it's not usually a good idea to edit your question to add a totally separate question like that.  Your question title doesn't reflect your new question, so people who could answer it might not find it.  If an answer to a question leads you to a new question that isn't directly an extension/modification of the original question, you should post that as a separate question.

Comment: Sorry about that, in the future I'll remember to make two separate questions when I have such a major detour from my original question. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is returning an instance of `Quux`.  The type of an instance is its class.  So the type of your `Quux` instance is `Quux`.

This doesn't really have anything to do with your metaclass.  It's the normal behavior for any old user-defined class:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
>>> f = Foo()
>>> type(f)
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Foo is a class.  `f` is an instance of Foo, so `type(f)` is Foo.

To answer your second question: just don't pass `thing` to the superclass.  Just do `return super(Quux, cls).__new__(cls)`.